# Scrape all google search result for a specific name

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, google-search-api

I think the question has been answered here before,but i could not find the desired topic.I am a newbie in web scraping.I have to develop a script that will take all the google search result for a specific name.Then it will grab the related data against that name and if there is found more than one,the data will be grouped according to their names.

All I know is that,google has some kind of restriction on scraping.They provide a custom search api.I still did not use that api,but hoping to get all the resulted links corresponding to a query from that api. But, could not understand what will be the ideal process to do the scraping of the information from that links.Any tutorial link or suggestion is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have provided a bit more what you have been doing, it does not sound like you even tried to solve it yourself.

Anyway, if you are still on it:

You can scrape Google through two ways, one is allowed one is not allowed.
a) Use their API, you can get around 2k results a day.
 You can up it to around 3k a day for 2000 USD/year. You can up it more by getting in contact with them directly.
You will not be able to get accurate ranking positions from this method, if you only need a lower number of requests and are mainly interested in getting some websites according to a keyword that's the choice.
Starting point would be here: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

b) You can scrape the real search results
That's the only way to get the true ranking positions, for SEO purposes or to track website positions. Also it allows to get a large amount of results, if done right.
You can Google for code, the most advanced free (PHP) code I know is at http://scraping.compunect.com
However, there are other projects and code snippets.
You can start off at 300-500 requests per day and this can be multiplied by multiple IPs. Look at the linked article if you want to go that route, it explains it in more details and is quite accurate.

That said, if you choose route b) you break Googles terms, so either do not accept them or make sure you are not detected. If Google detects you, your script will be banned by IP/captcha. Not getting detected should be a priority.